# How to stop redundant inputs when the output doesn't work?

Tags: python

I have a chunk of code written in python that rolls dice with any number of sides. Sometimes the output is zero, and I wrote around it, but in doing so it just reasserts the input instead of automatically fixing it. I want it so that if the output is zero, it re-rolls without it asking again.

```
from random import randrange

def Rolling(b):
   a = 1

   in1 = raw_input('Roll out of %d' % (b))
   if in1 == 'roll' or in1 == 'Roll' or in1 == 'r':
     irand = randrange(b)
     if irand == 0:
      Rolling(b)
     else:
      print "Your roll is %d out of %d" % (irand, b)       
      Rolling(b)
   elif in1 == 'Change' or in1 == 'change':
     in2 = int(raw_input('How many sides on the new die?'))
     b = in2
     Rolling(b)
   elif in1 == 'reroll' or in1 == 'Reroll':
     irand = randrange(b)
     if irand == 1 or irand == 0:
      Rolling(b)
     else:
      print "Your roll is %d out of %d" % (irand, b)
      Rolling(b)
   else:    print "Please Type <roll  in order to roll the dice."
     Rolling(b) # using recursion to call again incase of erroneous input

Rolling(10)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that part of the problem you're having is that you've used recursion to perform a non-recursive task.  Recursion is suited for a task that you can break down by simple steps, getting closer to the end in every call.  This task is not guaranteed to terminate, so recursion is not a good fit.

In fact, this program has no exit; it's an infinite loop, reading input and reacting in one of several ways.  This is properly a **while** loop, which you could handle with a "quit" input, too.  Something like this:

```
choice = raw_input('Roll out of %d ' % (b))
while choice.lower() != "quit":
    ...
```

That will handle your loop much better.

As for the zero rolls, the cleanest way to avoid zeros is to not roll them in the first place.  I think that you probably intend Rolling(10) to be a D10, producing values in the range 1-10 inclusive, in a uniform distribution.  randrange(10) gives you integerse 0-9 in a uniform distribution, so all you have to do is add 1 to the result:

```
irand = randrange(b) + 1
```

or change the limits of the call:

```
irand = randrange(1, b+1)
```

If you truly want numbers in the range 1-9, then write your code to exclude 0:

```
irand = randrange(1, b)
```